# Mapping values into a new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset (~7000 rows) that I have imported in Pandas for some "data wrangling" but I need some pointers in the right direction to take the next step. My data looks something like the below and it is a description of a structure with several sub levels. `B`, `D` and again `B` are sub levels to `A`. `C`is a sub level to `B`. and so on...

Level, Name
0, A
1, B
2, C
1, D
2, E
3, F
3, G
1, B
2, C

But i want something like the below, with `Name` and `Mother_name` on the same row:

Level, Name, Mother_name
1, B, A
2, C, B
1, D, A
2, E, D
3, F, E
3, G, E
1, B, A
2, C, B

Comment: can you fully specify the `Name -> Mother_name` mapping (preferable with a dictionary)?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I can specify the mapping easily (do you have any tips how i could do that?). The list is ~7000 rows long with up to 10 levels. A `K` could for example have the children `D` and `G`. A `M`could have the children `D` and `X`. The mother of `D`in the first example is `K` and in the second example `X`. Sorry if my explanation is confusing.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the drawing board on both your data schema and this question. It's not clear how the derived column is computed. The size of the dataframe is irrelevant when the problem is properly formulated.

Comment: The data is a product Bill Of Material. An assembly with several sub assemblies. The top assembly contains for example "bolts" and "nuts" but the sub assemblies can also contain bolts and nuts of the same kind. This could maybe explain the strange looking data schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the format correctly, the parent of a `name` depends on the
nearest prior row whose `level` is one less than the current row's `level`.

Your DataFrame has a modest number of rows (~7000). So there is little harm (to
performance) in simply iterating through the rows. If the DataFrame were very
large, you often get better performance if you can use column-wise vectorized Pandas
operations instead of row-wise iteration. However, in this case it appears that
using column-wise vectorized Pandas operations is awkward and
overly-complicated. So I believe row-wise iteration is the best choice here.

Using `df.iterrows` to perform row-wise iteration, you can simply record the current parents for every level as you go, and fill in the "mother"s as appropriate:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'level': [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2],
                   'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'B', 'C']})

parent = dict()
mother = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    parent[row['level']] = row['name']
    mother.append(parent.get(row['level']-1))
df['mother'] = mother
print(df)
```

yields

```
   level name mother
0      0    A   None
1      1    B      A
2      2    C      B
3      1    D      A
4      2    E      D
5      3    F      E
6      3    G      E
7      1    B      A
8      2    C      B
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can specify the mapping of the two columns in something like a dictionary, then you can just use the `map` method of the original column.

```
import pandas
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'B', 'C']

# name -> sublevel
sublevel_map = {
    'A': 'A',
    'B': 'A',
    'C': 'B',
    'D': 'A',
    'E': 'D',
    'F': 'E',
    'G': 'E'
}

df = pandas.DataFrame({'Name': names})
df['Sublevel'] = df['Name'].map(sublevel_map)
```

Which gives you:

```
  Name Sublevel
0    A        A
1    B        A
2    C        B
3    D        A
4    E        D
5    F        E
6    G        E
7    B        A
8    C        B
```