# Pandas dataframe lookup a value in different dataframe and assign a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 different dataframes.
The first one looks like:

```
     joint  label     x    z      y    pt
0        1    NaN  50.4  0.0  -8.40    10
1        2  shell  52.2  0.0  -8.40    20
2        3  shell  54.0  0.0  -8.40    30
3        4  shell  55.8  0.0  -8.40    40
4        5  shell  57.6  0.0  -8.40    50
```

and my second dataframe looks like:

```
     member  joint1  joint2        joint1_pt        joint2_pt
0         1       1       2                0                0
1         2       2       3                0                0
2         3       3       4                0                0
3         4       4       5                0                0
```

I would like take use the ***pt value*** that corresponds on a specific jointe and use it on the second dataframe so it will look like the following:

```
     member  joint1  joint2        joint1_pt        joint2_pt
0         1       1       2                10              20
1         2       2       3                20              30
2         3       3       4                30              40
3         4       4       5                40              50
```

can you please help me with an example/idear on how should i approach this?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You can use `pd.DataFrame.to_dict` (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012505/python-pandas-dataframe-columns-convert-to-dict-key-and-value)) and `pd.Series.map` (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561517/mapping-values-into-a-new-dataframe-column)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` created from `Series` with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.set_index.html) and [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) as pointed in [P-robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419268/pandas-dataframe-lookup-a-value-in-different-dataframe-and-assign-a-value#comment71984004_42419268) in comments:

```
d = df1.set_index('joint')['pt'].to_dict()
#mapping by Series works, but a bit slowier
#d = df1.set_index('joint')['pt']
print (d)
{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50}

df2['joint1_pt'] = df2['joint1'].map(d)
df2['joint2_pt'] = df2['joint2'].map(d)
print (df2)
   member  joint1  joint2  joint1_pt  joint2_pt
0       1       1       2         10         20
1       2       2       3         20         30
2       3       3       4         30         40
3       4       4       5         40         50
```

Comment: i try to implement your code and i get NaN in the joint1_pt and joint2_pt columns

Comment: Check dtypes, maybe need convert to str or int like `df2['joint1_pt'] = df2['joint1'].astype(str).map(d)` or `df2['joint1_pt'] = df2['joint1'].astype(int).map(d)` because need same.

Comment: Same in dict and in columns joint1 and join2.

Comment: do you know why the first line of your code in my case returns string type for the keys of the dicts? as a second line i add this line `d = {int(k):int(v) for k,v in d.items()}` and it works now. but curious why in yours return integer type for your keys. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

you can use [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), after merging ,assign pt to joint1_pt & joint2_pt , finally drop unwanted columns.

```
df= pd.merge(df2,df1[['joint','pt']], right_on='joint',left_on='joint1',how='left')
df= pd.merge(df,df1[['joint','pt']], right_on='joint',left_on='joint2',how='left')
df[['joint1_pt','joint2_pt']] =df[['pt_x','pt_y']] 
df=df[['member','joint1','joint2','joint1_pt','joint2_pt']]
print df
```

Output

```
   member  joint1  joint2  joint1_pt  joint2_pt
0       1       1       2         10         20
1       2       2       3         20         30
2       3       3       4         30         40
3       4       4       5         40         50
```

Comment: the df1['joint','pt'] seems not to work. I get a KeyError: ('joint', 'pt'). Even when i try to print this it doesnt work. But when i try to print them seperately it works. Any idea?

Comment: thanks for your assistance! It works without giving and error but do you have any idea why it returns a NaN for all entries in the joint1_pt and joint2_pt columns?

Comment: with the sample data, it works fine, It may be possible that 'joint' values are not matching to joint1 & joint2 in those cases it may be Nan